# Filter dataset with column not like any value in a list

Tags: r, vector, filter

I want to filter a dataset with a column not like any value in a list

I tried different ways but they don't work

```r
month <- c("2022-02", "2022-02", "2022-03", "2022-03", "2022-05","2022-06", "2022-07","2022-02", "2022-04","2022-5","2022-6","2022-7")
total_amount <- c(100, 200, 500, 600, 700, 300, 500, 900, 900, 600, 500, 700)
merchant_name <- c("fpay", "gpay", "upay", "zpay","tpay","spay","mpay", "dpay", "bpay", "opay", "npay", "ypay")

df <- data.frame(month, total_amount, merchant_name)
```

```r
a <- c("fpay", "gpay", "upay", "zpay","tpay","spay","mpay")
df1 = df %>% list.filter(!merchant_name %like% a)
```

or

```r
df1 = subset(df, !merchant_name%like% a)
```

or

```r
df1 <- df[apply(df,1,function(x) sum(!x %like% a)>=1),]
```

However, the number of observations of df1 is the same to df's, not filter at all.
And I receive a warning message:

In grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Please kindly help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO, tracy! This question is not really reproducible, we don't know the values of `df`, `x1`, `x2`, etc, and it will help to clarify things if you can please add your expected output (given those sample inputs). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I just add an example in the question above. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `%in%`? It handles multiples just fine. Are you really needing regex? (What is `list.filter`? I can't find it.)

Answer (score 0):

If these are substring, use `grepl` after `paste`ing the elements in 'a' with `collapse = "|"`

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(a, collapse = "|"), merchant_name))
```

Or using `%like%`

```
subset(df, Reduce(`|`, lapply(a, \(x) merchant_name %like% x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
df[! df$merchant_name %in% a, ]
```

To understand what this code, let's work our way inside out.

First, the expression `df$merchant_name %in% a`. This creates a *logical vector*  (a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values) with an entry for each element in `df$merchant_name` (and hence for each row in `df`). The corresponding entry for each row is `TRUE` if that entry is in `a` and `FALSE` otherwise (technically there are special cases if the entry itself is `NA`).

Then, `! df$merchant_name %in% a` negates the previous expression. This matches our intent to find those rows that ***don't*** match the list.

Finally, we can use the previous expression to subset/filter the df for the desired entries. To do this, we'll use the previous expression as an *index vector* for the row position (e.g. In `df[i, j]`, `i` is the index vector for the row-position and `j` is an index vector for the column-position.). Bringing us full circle:

```
df[! df$merchant_name %in% a, ]
```